# compare a string against a process name

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

i want to do this... IF notepad is in the foreground it opens the calculator... if another program is open does nothing... the notepad is oepn manualy... "Start, Notepad"... i have this code to "see" if notepad is open... dont know how to continue D: i know i have to use

```
if (switch == 0)
{
if (SOMETHING == "Notepad")
{
   var switch = 1 //so it doesnt enters in a loop
   OPEN CALCULATOR //irrelevant, i may use another part of otrher code that is already working
   }
}
```

the "switch" variable is going to be 0 from the beginning of the code, so that is going to work (hope)

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

Process GetActiveProcess()
{
    IntPtr hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
    uint pid;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out pid);
    Process p = Process.GetProcessById((int)pid);
    return p;
}
```

the problem is that i dont know what to put on "SOMETHING" to use the rest of the code, and Where or How to use the If...

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
Process[] notePadProcesses  = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad.exe");
IntPtr activeWindowHandle = GetForegroundWindow();

if (notePadProcesses != null && notePadProcesses.Length > 0
    && notePadProcesses.Any(p=>p.MainWindowHandle == activeWindowHandle))
{
 // notepad is open in the foreground.
 switch = 1;
 // OPEN Calculator or whatever you need to.
}
else
{
 // notepad is either not open, or not open in the foreground.
}
```

basically we use the C# friendly Process class to find all the open notepad processes.
Then find if it is an active process and go from there.

please be careful using activewindow logic, because many a time, they result in race conditions where by the time you determine a process is active and try to do something, it may no longer be an active process. tread carefully.

Comment: is not working... i have a problem with not finding the "any" (underlined red this is the error)
'System.Array/' does not contain a definition for 'Any' and no extension method 'Any' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using  directive  or an assembly reference?)

my "using" are this

Comment: I was missing somethingn :p THAAANKS LOVE YOU : D Its been three days trying to do this.. n.n

Comment: not woriking how it should... the program starts... do whatever it already did... no way to know whats wrong...

Comment: thanks you very VERY much, it's the third day... so im a little frustrated for not being able to acomplish this... but your help (from all of you) made me understand a lot of this program... so really... thanks... i will keep trying...

Comment: you need to include 'using System.Linq;' to use the Any() extension method. and if you're still getting issues, let us know the specific issue with code snippet and we'll try to assist.